# Browser-update message Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

The browser update script causes the page to load very slowly in IE11 and the message doesn't display when I hit F12 for developer tools and select IE8, or on another computer that is running IE8. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DS Arts</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slider').cycle({

    fx:         'fade',
    timeout:    3000,
    next:       '#next',
    prev:       '#prev'


    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $buoop = {vs:{i:8,f:15,o:12.1,s:5.1}}; 
$buoop.ol = window.onload; 
window.onload=function(){ 
 try {if ($buoop.ol) $buoop.ol();}catch (e) {} 
 var e = document.createElement("script"); 
 e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
 e.setAttribute("src", "//browser-update.org/update.js"); 
 document.body.appendChild(e); 
} 
</script> 



<style type="text/css">
#hero {
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
}
#slider {
    position: relative;
}
#slidewrap {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
}
.myCaption {
    color: #F6F0E2;
    backface-visibility: visible;
    background: #000000;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: small;
    width: 685px;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    z-index: 99;
    padding-left: 15px;
    top: -35px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#next {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 225px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#prev {
    widows: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 225px;
    left::0px;
    z-index: 99;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#hero:hover #next {
    opacity: .8;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
#hero:hover #prev {
    opacity: .8;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
</style>

<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<body bgcolor="#3097B9">
</head> 



<div class="page-wrap">
<body>

 <header>
  <div id="headerwrap"><div><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="DS Arts logo" width="529" height="143" class="headerimage"/></a></div> 

   <img src="images/Factory.png" alt="" width="400" height="136" id="buildingimg"/></div>


</header>
<div id="navwrap"><nav id="navbar"><ul>
    <p><a href="index.html">Home</a></p>
    <p><a href="design.html">Design</a></p>
    <p><a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a></p>
    <p><a href="fabrication.html">Fabrication</a></p>
    <p><a href="installation.html">Installation</a></p>
    <p><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></p>
    <p><a href="clientlist.html">Client List</a></p>
    <p><a href="contact.html" id="16">Contact</a></p>
  </ul>

</nav></div>


<div id="wrapper">

<div id="paragraph">
<h1><a href="design.html">Design</a>, Display,<br> <a href="fabrication.html">Fabrication</a>,<br> <a href="installation.html">Installation</a>...</h1>
<p class="p">A picture is worth a thousand words. We’re DS ARTS. We’re in the business of creating amazing environments that motivate, impress, and make a statement through our design, production, and installation expertise. We work with a wide spectrum of clients to create trade shows, special events, showrooms, restaurant and retail interiors, sales and marketing centers, specialized decor and entertainment venues. Of course, everything is created with each client’s unique needs in mind. Take a look... We think you’ll like what you see...</p></div>

<div class="rotator">

<div id="hero">

<div id="next"><img src="images/right.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""/></div>
<div id="prev"><img src="images/left.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""/></div>


     <div id="slider">

     <div id="slidewrap">
     <img src="images/mickey.jpg" width="700" height="500" alt=""/>
     <span class="myCaption">MATTEL - New York Toy Fair</span>
     </div>

     <div id="slidewrap">
     <img src="images/Lenox square.jpg" width="700" height="500" alt=""/>
     <span class="myCaption">LENOX SQUARE MALL - Atlanta</span>
     </div>

     <div id="slidewrap">
     <img src="images/fisher.jpg" width="700" height="500" alt=""/>
     <span class="myCaption">FISHE PRICE JPMA SHOW - Dallas</span>
     </div>

     <div id="slidewrap">
     <img src="images/DSC03399.JPG" width="700" height="500" alt=""/>
     <span class="myCaption">VICTORY PARK DISCOVERY CENTER - Dallas</span>
     </div>

     <div id="slidewrap">
     <img src="images/megazord.jpg" width="700" height="500" alt=""/>
     <span class="myCaption">BANDAI - New York Toy Fair</span>
     </div>

     <div id="slidewrap">
     <img src="images/BIRD CAGES.jpg" width="700" height="500" alt=""/>
     <span class="myCaption">COWBOYS STADIUM - Arlington</span>
     </div>

     <div id="slidewrap">
     <img src="images/benten.jpg" width="700" height="500" alt=""/>
     <span class="myCaption">BANDAI - New York Toy Fair</span>
     </div>


</div>

</div>
</div> 
</body>
</div>
</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  <div id="footwrap">
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Phone:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fax: 214-565-7859 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:dkolbo@dsarts.com"></a><p/>
  </div>
</footer>


</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry that someone found that this was not useful, and I have been trying to figure this out for two days, so I have certainly made an effort. On Browser-update.org it just says to paste this into your source page. That is what I did and it isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is the script that isn't working:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
var $buoop = {vs:{i:8,f:15,o:12.1,s:5.1}}; 
$buoop.ol = window.onload; 
window.onload=function(){ 
 try {if ($buoop.ol) $buoop.ol();}catch (e) {} 
 var e = document.createElement("script"); 
 e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
 e.setAttribute("src", "//browser-update.org/update.js"); 
 document.body.appendChild(e); 
} 
</script>

Comment: are you running this on a webserver or are you testing it locally in your browser?

Comment: I'm testing it locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is assuming you are running on a webserver, so while you are running it locally change

```
 e.setAttribute("src", "//browser-update.org/update.js");
```

to

```
 e.setAttribute("src", "http://browser-update.org/update.js");
```

**But remember to change it back when you run it on your live site!**

So just to explain fully:

replace

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $buoop = {vs:{i:8,f:15,o:12.1,s:5.1}}; 
$buoop.ol = window.onload; 
window.onload=function(){ 
 try {if ($buoop.ol) $buoop.ol();}catch (e) {} 
 var e = document.createElement("script"); 
 e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
 e.setAttribute("src", "//browser-update.org/update.js"); 
 document.body.appendChild(e); 
} 
</script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $buoop = {vs:{i:8,f:15,o:12.1,s:5.1}}; 
$buoop.ol = window.onload; 
window.onload=function(){ 
 try {if ($buoop.ol) $buoop.ol();}catch (e) {} 
 var e = document.createElement("script"); 
 e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
 e.setAttribute("src", "http://browser-update.org/update.js"); // this line changes!
 document.body.appendChild(e); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Oh, I see. But it still doesn't display the message.

Comment: @mytaquitos: could that be because your browser is up to date?

Comment: Internet Explorer has a developer tool that allows you to view a page in older versions of IE, so no.

Comment: @mytaquitos The message is being displayed the first time it runs on an "old" browser. It appears again after 24 hours so as to be subtle. Start a "private browsing session" and test your page to see the message.

Comment: This trick is not needed if you're running your website on a local server. If you do keep `http`, you might need to change it to `https` on your production site if it has SSL.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the accepted answer, keep in mind that the "*notification will only appear once a day by default*", as their [github](https://github.com/browser-update/browser-update) page says (which is what @KitKat has pointed out earlier). If needed, you can customize this behavior using `reminder` option in your JS snippet. Their [website](http://browser-update.org/customize.html) has more on that. This took me quite some time to figure out... Hope this helps someone.